# What is the purpose of `review_entity` table?

Tags: magento2

Simple question. What is the purpose of `review_entity` table? The first one maps to user product reviews. What are those other entries for?

```
entity_id   entity_code
        1   product
        2   customer
        3   category
```

Comment: https://blog.magepsycho.com/import-product-reviews-in-magento-via-sql/

Comment: @RkRathod thanks, but I don't see an answer to my question.

Answer (score 0):

It appears that `customer` and `category` are remnants from some earlier implementation.

In *\Magento\Review\Model\Review* there are corresponding const values defined for all three:

```
/**
 * Product entity review code
 */
const ENTITY_PRODUCT_CODE = 'product';

/**
 * Customer entity review code
 */
const ENTITY_CUSTOMER_CODE = 'customer';

/**
 * Category entity review code
 */
const ENTITY_CATEGORY_CODE = 'category';
```

However, there are no further uses of either `ENTITY_CUSTOMER_CODE` or `ENTITY_CATEGORY_CODE` outside of *\Magento\Review\Setup\Patch\Data\InitReviewStatusesAndData*, which is the setup script that populates `review_entity`.

This is also true in CE v1.9.x, so any uses of "customer" and "category" reviews were deprecated before Magento 2.